# getting spim (mips compiler ) on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation

I want to install `spim (mips compiler)` to my ubuntu 12.04 machine .Is there anyone to help me ?

Comment: So what is the problem? What do you get when you execute this command in terminal: `sudo apt-get install spim` ? Reply..

Comment: @SauravKumar thank you I got it. I though I need to do something else.

Comment: See, there is nothing you've to do. Installing software in Ubuntu is as easy as pie.

Comment: @Eday answer updated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can install spim ( spim - MIPS R2000/R3000 emulator  ) it with

```
sudo apt-get install spim
```

from your terminal.

in 12.04 you can have a Graphical MIPS32 Assembly language emulator with spim installation.https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/spim/

@OP

- QTspim 32-bit

  http://sourceforge.net/projects/spimsimulator/files/qtspim_9.1.6_linux32.deb/download
- QTspim 64-bit

  http://sourceforge.net/projects/spimsimulator/files/qtspim_9.1.6_linux64.deb/download

for more information : http://lambda-pancakes.blogspot.in/2012/10/qtspim-in-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: thanks for reply. I did it. Do you recommend a misp compiler with GUI ? I think misp works only in terminal ?

Comment: @Eday in 12.04 spim is a GUI https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/spim/

Comment: I heard QTspim is also available. Do you know how could I install it into ubuntu ? sudo apt-get install qtspim does not work

Comment: @Eday http://lambda-pancakes.blogspot.in/2012/10/qtspim-in-ubuntu-1204.html there you go.

Answer (score 0):

the process I followed was:

to install just command line spim:

```
sudo apt-get install spim
```

to get the "new" qtspim version:

first:

`sudo apt-get install qt-sdk`

then download the latest stable *.deb version at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/spimsimulator/files/

that launched the installer and everything went well.